# Gtk clipboard owner-change event: detecting whether the changer is me

Tags: python, clipboard, gtk3

It is easy to set the contents of the normal ctrl-C ctrl-V clipboard in Gtk 3 in a Python 3 app, with something like

```py
clipboard = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
clipboard.set_text("It worked!, -1)
```

It is also easy to monitor the clipboard for changes, using the Clipboard object's `owner-change` signal.

However, I would like to ignore `owner-change` in my app if it was **my** app that *set* the contents of the clipboard, and I don't know how. The `owner-change` signal passes an `owner` parameter which points to a `Gdk.Window`, but I never explicitly create a window in my app; I assume that Gtk quietly creates one for me because there needs to be some X window around to own the contents of the clipboard. I can get that X window's ID when the clipboard owner changes with something like:

```py
def clipboardChanged(clipboard, owner_change):
    print("New owner is", owner_change.owner.get_xid())

clipboard.connect('owner-change', clipboardChanged)
```

This new owner window obviously belongs to my app, but how do I find its xid ahead of time? That is: how can I tell from an `owner-change` signal that the new owner is *me*?

(Note: if I set the contents of the clipboard twice, I get two `owner-change` signals, and `owner_change.reason` is `NEW_OWNER` every time, so this is not reliable: in particular, `NEW_OWNER` is also sent for "the same owner set it again", and not just for "a *different* owner now owns the clipboard".)